# Why curated lists contributors use the forks instead wiki tool?

Tags: github

Github is full of curated lists ([example](https://github.com/jnv/lists)).

Why curated lists contributors use the forks instead github-wiki tool?

Answer (score 2):

For ease of viewing, most such lists are presented as README.md files in the main repository (where they are shown by default when viewing the repo). As such, they are much like regular program code.

Therefore, the easiest way to edit them, is as you would code - being able to edit from the page, creating your own fork as you do so, and then from that, making a pull-request.

Comment: It's easy if you already have the git client on your desktop. You can't do it in web-interface.

Comment: I make regular minor edits to repos right there in the web interface. When viewing a file on the site, right next to the "Raw / Blame / History" buttons are "Open this file in GitHub for Windows" and "Edit this file" (on the site)

Comment: Yes, I don't know about it, thank you. I think not all of contributors know about it too. And you do not use the forks in this case. And wiki is much easy, I suppose.